# How to use SelectNodes method in the case of not before a specific tag

Tags: html, xml, xpath, html-agility-pack

My html code is sloppy, so I want to get all nodes that has class="abcd" but this tag should not come after class="qwe". how can I achieve it in HTMLAgilityPack.dll?
for example, here is my html sample:

```
           <div class="qwe">
              <div class="abcd">
               ....other tags
              </div>
           </div>
              <div class="abcd">
               ....other tags
              </div>
              <div class="abcd">
               ....other tags
              </div>
```

so SelectNodes method should only return the last two tags, not the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//div[@class='abcd' and not(ancestor::*[@class='qwe'])]")